# How I can count documents in collection MongoDB Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have many documents in collection
So,How I can count documents in collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Obtain a `MongoCollection` or `DBCollection` instance for the collection.  For example:

   ```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(
            new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017));
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("mydb");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("test");
   ```
2. Call the `count()` method on the collection object.

---

Apparently, the above is for the MongoDB 3.x driver APIs.

If you are using the MongoDB 4.x APIs, you should use the `countDocuments()` method provided by the `MongoCollection` interface.  Something like this.

```
MongoClient  mongoClient = MongoClients.create(...);
MongoCollection collection = mongoClient.getCollection("test"); \

long count = collection.countDocuments();
```

(The 3.x APIs are now described as "legacy" APIs.  However, I could not see anything in the MongoDB documentation to say that they are actually deprecated.  If some can find something that states that, please post the URL below.)

Comment: In the newer versions of MongoDB and Java Driver `count` method is _deprecated_. Instead, use [countDocuments](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/index.html).